Is there a way to use a ML model created in Azure AutoML within Designer?
I know I can create custom code modules in Azure Designer, but is there a way to connect my ML model I created in AutoML natively?
The AutoML model is using XGBoost, which doesn't appear to be an option under the ML Components feature of Designer. My goal was to create a low code solution, so I'd prefer not to use the custom Python code component.
Any ideas?
Built model using AutoML, need to connect to existing data pipeline in Designer

In Azure ML Designer v1, which is Classic prebuilt, loading the model to build a pipeline is not supported.

Only in Designer v2, which is Custom, is possible. Below is Designer v2, where you can add your model.

First, register the best model from the Auto ML training job.
Click on Register model after the training job is completed.

In the next window, the best model is automatically selected.

Then, click next, give a name to the model, and click on register.

Next, when creating a Designer v2 pipeline, your registered model appears in the left model tab as shown below.

Use it further in your pipeline.

This is super useful information, but I don't see a Model tab between Data and Component? I only have the two tabs.

In 2nd screenshot I said about using designer v2. Follow that

I'm using v2 designer I believe. I clicked Custom->Create a new pipeline using custom components. I just don't see a Model tab between Data and Component?
